# Why JavaFX ScrollPane pannable not working, and why the box aroung the circle?

Tags: javafx, fxml

This my main class....

```
package software;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

    public class FXMLExample extends Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            try {
                ScrollPane root = (ScrollPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_example.fxml"));
                Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.show();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

The FXML file....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<ScrollPane fx:id="sp" hbarPolicy="NEVER" maxHeight="-Infinity"
    maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity"
    pannable="true" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" vbarPolicy="NEVER"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="software.FXMLExampleController">
    <content>
        <Group>
            <children>
                <Circle fill="DODGERBLUE" radius="100.0" stroke="BLACK"
                    strokeType="INSIDE" />
            </children>
        </Group>
    </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

This is my Controller...

```
package software;

import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXMLExampleController {

    @FXML
    ScrollPane sp;

    final double SCALE_DELTA = 1.1;

    @FXML
    protected void initialize() {

        double scrollDelta = 0;

        System.out.println("In initialize() method");

        System.out.println("sp:" + sp);

        // boardersp.sceneProperty().addListener( (o, oldEvent, newEvent) ->
        // {
        System.out.println("Gleep000");
        System.out.println("Gleep000.0");
        System.out.println("sp: " + sp.getClass().getName());
        sp.sceneProperty();
        System.out.println("Gleep001");
        System.out.println("Gleep002");
        sp.sceneProperty().addListener((o, oldEvent, newEvent) -> {
            if (oldEvent != null) {
                // remove your stuff from the scene
                System.out.println("In addListner() remove");
            }
            if (newEvent != null) {
                // add your stuff to the scene
                System.out.println("In addListner() add");
                newEvent.setOnScroll(new EventHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(Event event) {
                        System.out.println("In handle scroll event");

                        ScrollEvent se = (ScrollEvent) event;
                        double scrollDelta = ((ScrollEvent) event).getDeltaY();
                        System.out.println("\tscrollDelta: " + scrollDelta);

                        if (scrollDelta == 0) {
                            return;
                        }

                        double scaleFactor = (se.getDeltaY() > 0) ? SCALE_DELTA : 1 / SCALE_DELTA;

                        System.out.println("\tscaleFactor: " + scaleFactor);
                        // amount of scrolling in each direction in
                        // scrollContent coordinate
                        // units
                        // Point2D scrollOffset =
                        // figureScrollOffset(topScrollPaneGroup,
                        // topScrollPane);

                        System.out.println("\tBefore::boardersp.getTranslateX: " + sp.getTranslateX());
                        System.out.println("\tBefore::boardersp.sp.getScaleX: " + sp.getScaleX());
                        sp.setScaleX(sp.getScaleX() * scaleFactor);
                        System.out.println("\tAfter::boardersp.getTranslateX: " + sp.getTranslateX());
                        System.out.println("\tAfter::boardersp.sp.getScaleX: " + sp.getScaleX());

                        System.out.println("\tBefore::boardersp.getTranslateY: " + sp.getTranslateY());
                        System.out.println("\tBefore::boardersp.sp.getScaleY: " + sp.getScaleY());
                        sp.setScaleY(sp.getScaleY() * scaleFactor);
                        System.out.println("\tAfter::boardersp.getTranslateY: " + sp.getTranslateY());
                        System.out.println("\tAfter::boardersp.sp.getScaleY: " + sp.getScaleY());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Why the box around the solid circle when the mouse wheel zooms out?
Why does the "pannable" setting not work?

Comment: You're applying the zoom to the entire scroll pane... So the scroll pane itself is changing size. The box you're seeing is the scroll pane itself. It never scrolls because the content is never bigger than the viewport (because the entire scroll pane, and content, are getting resized together). You want to zoom the content (but I don't have time to figure out the full fix right now).

Comment: Thanks  that did fix the zoom part.  Now still need to figure out why pannable is not working.

Comment: I found out what the issue was.  It seems if the scene graph is not outside the pane the "pannable" feature will not work.  The scene graph must have elements that render outside the scrollpane for the "pannable" feature to start working.